# Why do I get error SQLSTATE42000 in PHP/MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, xampp, localhost

I am working on a project using PHP and MySQL.

I have an HTML table that has 3 columns into which I load data from my "Tasks" table in MySQL. The columns are: `id`, `taskname` and a button column that when clicked on, takes you to the `Edit` page for the relevant task (I pass the task id as a URL) - `http://localhost/tasks/?edit&id=3`

The problem arises when I try to load the details about this task. This is the code:

```
if(isset($_GET["id"]))
    {
        try
       {
           $sql = "SELECT * FROM tasks WHERE id = :id";
           $result = $pdo->prepare($sql);
           $result->bindValue(":id", $_GET["id"]);
           $result = $pdo->query($sql);
       }
       catch(PDOException $e)
       {
          $error = "Error trying to load task - " . $e->getMessage();
          include "error.php";
          exit();
        }

        foreach($result as $task)
        {
           $tasktext = $task["task"];
           $id = $task["id"];
        }

        $title = "Edit task";    
            $action = "edittask";
            $button = "Edit task";
            include 'form.php';
    exit();
    resetParameters();
```

I get the following error:

`Error trying to load task - SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ':id' at line 1`

When I replace the `WHERE id = :id` with `WHERE id = 3` for example it works and loads the details about the task however I simply cannot get it to load the details about the task I have clicked on in the previous screen.

Could anyone spot anything wrong with my code/logic and point me in the right direction please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use [execute()](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.execute.php) not [query()](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.query.php) when using prepared query's:

- [execute()](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.execute.php)  PDOStatement::execute — Executes a prepared statement.
- [query()](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.query.php) PDO::query — Executes an SQL statement.

Try:

```
<?php 
try
{
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM tasks WHERE id = :id";
    $query = $pdo->prepare($sql);
    $query->bindValue(":id", $_GET["id"]);
    $query->execute();
    $result = $query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
}
catch(PDOException $e)
{
    $error = "Error trying to load task - " . $e->getMessage();
    include "error.php";
    exit();
}
?>
```

Comment: thank you for your help. It works! So why did it work when I replaced the :id with 3?

Comment: Because query() is used for raw querys E.G no bound parameters.

Comment: Understand, thank you so much for your help. Will accept the answer in a few minutes as it doesn't let me accept it at the moment

Comment: np, glad to help, I added some links to the manual for thos two PDO methods.